# Static site generator that supports URLs without trailing slash and file extension

Tags: linux, open-source, static-site-generator

I need a static site generator (FLOSS, GNU/Linux) that can generate internal hyperlinks (to corresponding generated HTML files)

- without trailing slash, and
- without file extension.

This should be an intended/supported feature, not a hack.

For other file types (CSS, PDF, PNG, …), there should be the option to use file extensions.

#### Example

The SSG generates these files/directories:

```
blog.html
```

```
blog/hello-world.html
```

```
blog/hello-world/welcome.png
```

and these hyperlinks (in the navigation, in `link`-`canonical` elements, in the sitemap etc.):

```
/blog
```

```
/blog/hello-world
```

```
/blog/hello-world/welcome.png
```

---

From what I found, [**Hugo** doesn’t support it](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/492), **nanoc** doesn’t support it, and it’s [unclear if **Lektor** supports it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46879885/1591669).

Comment: Sitemap? And just skip the file extension – or only point to "directories" (`/blog`, `/blog/hello-world`: the former definitely is a directory, the latter might just have the `.html` extension stripped)? Generate a tree? Should it be generated "on the fly" (e.g. when a visitor comes to the sitemap page), or "materialize" them into a HTML file?

Comment: @Izzy: A sitemap might be one of the things where the SSG needs to generate URLs, other are the navigation, breadcrumbs, `link`-`canonical` elements etc. -- I need a regular SSG to build a website, i.e., it runs locally and it generates static files, which I then manually upload to a server. The problem with most SSGs I found is that they either append file extensions or generate `index.html` files, because this is what typical servers (like Apache) support of out of the box. So the SSG I need should just generate the URLs as I desire, and not care if servers can match these by default.

Comment: @Izzy: And the URL `/blog` should not show a directory, it should show a HTML file. On the server, this file would ideally have the name `blog.html`. If I have an image that should be available from the URL `/blog/img.png` (or blog posts etc.), the SSG would generate a directory named `blog` in addition. So on the server, I would have: `blog.html` (HTML file), `blog` (directory), `blog/hello-world.html` (HTML file) etc.

Comment: Ah, now I see. You might wish to integrate parts of your second comment with your question (especially "this is the existing structure – and that is what should be generated"; the "existing structure" is missing "up there"). Apart from that I obviously misinterpreted "static SITE generator", though the term was there (oops). But I'm in good company with that: even [Wikipedia has a different understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_site_generator), while you rather thought of something like [Jekyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jekyll_(software)), right?

Comment: @Izzy: Aye, edited my answer. To be clear, there is no "existing" structure; I need this for creating a new site, so how exactly it works on the file/directory level is up to the SSG, as long as I can get these URLs. But I guess the structure I mention is the one that makes the most sense. -- Yes, I mean tools like Jekyll (thanks for mentioning it! it [seems to support it now](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#extensionless-permalinks) -- when I checked some years ago, it didn’t).

Comment: [According to this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/916fkj/what_are_the_static_site_generators_that_support/e2whhqh/), Pelican seems to support it.